# show result from one table

Tags: sql

good day, i have these 3 tables...i.e.;

customer table

```
cust_id cust_name sales_employee
1       abc       1
2       cde       1
3       efg       2
```

transaction table

```
order_num   cust_id   sales_employee
1001        1         1 
1002        2         2
```

sales_employee table

```
sales_employee     employee name
1                  john doe
2                  jane doe
```

how can i show the employee name on both customer table and transaction table?
notice how the sales_employee can change per transaction, it does not necessarily have to be the same per customer.

please help.

Comment: If the employee changes during the transaction, which one do you want to show?

Comment: If you have any control over this design, change it.  The customer table should not have a sales_employee field.

Comment: @Dan It should just be renamed to CurrentSalesRep. Often, sales reps will shuffle between customers. On the transactions, you want to see who the sales rep was at the time of sale. This is fairly typical in some business setups. I think Marc may be new to DB's and is thrown-off by the fact that there are two kinds of sales-reps. "Current" and "point-in-time"

Comment: I guess it depends on the type of business.  If there is a real life relationship between sales reps and customers, that's a good way to store the data.  Otherwise, there should be no field in the customer table.

Comment: @DanBracuk Aye, think manufacturer and wholesale-purchaser

Comment: @Dan sales_employee at customer table is needed for historical purposes of the current sales employee. As for the transactions, sales_employee could change (that sales_employee resigned). So I want to see who is the current sales_employee and the sales_employee at the time of transaction.

Answer (score 1):

**To select customers with sales person name**

```
select 
  C.*, E.employee_name
from
  Customers as C
  inner join Sales_Employees as E on E.sales_employee = C.sales_employee
```

**To select transactions with customer name and salesperson name** (at the point in time of the transaction)

```
select 
  T.*, 
  E.employee_name as Trans_employee, 
  C.cust_name,
  EC.employee_name as Cust_employee
from
  Transactions as T
  inner join Sales_Employees as E on E.sales_employee = T.sales_employee
  inner join Customers as C on C.cust_id= T.cust_id
  inner join Sales_Employees as EC on EC.sales_employee = C.sales_employee
```

This code is meant to guide you, you will need to adjust it to match your table and field names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to show the sales_employee name for both Customers and Transactions? Like:

Comment: Yep, I modified the code to show one way of doing this. YOu need to join a second time to the employee table

Comment: But can I show the sales_employee name for both tables on one view?

Comment: @ Brian Webster Thanks for this! I have been searching for this sql for weeks!